# Управление свойством DOM-элемента через родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Доброго времени суток.
Задача: при наведении на элемент списка(li) рядом с ним должна появляться метка желтого цвета, а при нажатии на него метка должна ставится или сниматься.
Я добавил внутрь элемента списка span и дал ему стили. Не совсем понимаю как обратится к дочернему элементу списка(span), что бы метка появлялась только у того элемента, на который нажал, а не у всех сразу. Так же, надо что бы на 
Скрин https://prnt.sc/iaay1l

Прошу подсказать как обратиться только к дочернему элементу, а не ко всем элементам с таким же классом.

```css
ul {
  width: 350px;
}

.sorting_main {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.sorting_type__list,
.sorting_amount__list {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sorting_type__list:hover .checked-mark,
.sorting_amount__list:hover .checked-mark {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checked-mark {
  display: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #e6b738;
  border-radius: 1em;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="type">
  <li class="sorting_main sorting_type__list">Тип объекта <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></li>
  <li class="sorting_type__list" value="apartment">квартира <span class="checked-mark"></span></li>
  <li class="sorting_type__list" value="room">комната <span class="checked-mark"></span></li>
  <li class="sorting_type__list" value="house">дом <span class="checked-mark"></span></li>
  <li class="sorting_type__list" value="cottage">коттедж <span class="checked-mark"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `this` тебе в помощь

Comment: Я понимаю что надо использовать this, но я не знаю как обратиться исключительно к дочернему элементу, а не ко всем DOM-элементам с таким же классом.

$('.list_item__class').click(function(){
  $(this).и дальше не знаю как написать
 });

Comment: покажи весь код

Comment: `$(this).children'('span')`

Comment: @Air
Вот код https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxZedw#anon-signup

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду что-то типа такого?

```js
$(".element").click(
  function() {
    var element = $(this).hasClass("active")
    if (element) {
      $(this).removeClass("active")
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("active")
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.element {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.element span {
    display: none;
    background-color: #fc0;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.element:hover > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.active span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="element">1 <span></span></li>
  <li class="element">2 <span></span></li>
  <li class="element">3 <span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Именно оно, большое спасибо